# Opening a new QMainWindow crash after destructor

Tags: c++, qt, destructor, qmainwindow

A first MainWindow is open in the main ,then when I try to open a second
window the program crashes with a SIGABRT .
The debugger shows the following lines:

```
double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fffffffe340 ***

RTTI symbol not found for class 'QObject'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QObject'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QObject'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QObject'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QObject'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QObject'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QObject'
```

I want to understand what's the right way to call the destructor ,
if I do not set the Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose attribute the program works and
if I do the same in the second window ,(I.E i open a third window in the second QMainwindow) the program works even if i set the Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose attribute.Why I can't do that only in the first QMainWindow ?The one I open in the main?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    QTimer *t = new QTimer(this);
    connect(t,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(open_new()));
    t->start(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::open_new(){
    MainWindow2 *win_2 = new MainWindow2(0);
    win_2->show();
    this->close();
}
```

Comment: you can use delete this;

Comment: Show your main(). I bet the first MainWindow is a stack variable. You can (should) use DeleteOnClose if your MainWindow is created by the "new" operator only.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop

Comment: Btw, try to replace ` this->close();` with `QTimer::singleShot( 0, this, &QWidget::close );`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Qt all QWidgets are managed like this:

1. All destructors are virtual.
2. If a widget (well, in fact, any QObject) has a parent, then the parent deletes it (using `operator delete`) himself. That is, all child widgets must be created by the `operator new`, or must be destructed before the parent is (see @BenjaminT comment).
3. If a widget has no parent (i.e. 0) and has the attribute WA_DeleteOnClose set, then it initiates the call of the `operator delete` himself (by using a member function `deleteLater()`, see @BenjaminT comment), while processing the `close` signal (the actual `delete` gets called, well, later, i.e. not inside the slot code, see @DmitrySazonov comment). Again, (a) an application should not do this itself, because it's redundant; (b) a widget still should be created with the `operator new`.
4. If a widget has no parent, and has no WA_DeleteOnClose attribute set, then it's up to the calling application how to create and destruct it. For example, if QWidget is a stack variable, then it gets destructed automatically when returning from the corresponding function (as it's normal in C++).

In your case, the first MainWindow wasn't probably created with the `new operator`, so it mustn't have WA_DeleteOnClose attribute set. But the following code should work OK:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow* w = new MainWindow(0);
    // redundant if the attibute is set inside the class constructor
    //w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    w->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: For the point 3, it does not call `delete this`, but `deleteLater()` which is a bit different.

Comment: For point 2, not all child `QObject` must be created with `new`. The only constraint is that if they are not created with `new`, they must be destroyed before the call to their parent `~QObject()` destructor. Meaning, in particular, that it is safe to have a `QObject` stored as a member variable of its parent.

Comment: @BenjaminT Well, it's a part of a fool proof code. At the end of a day `delete` operator gets called anyway.

Comment: Sure in the end `delete` is called, but using `deleteLater()` means the call to `delete` is done later and it may have an impact somewhere.

Comment: It is normal to directly delete widget (without deleteLater), if you are not doing it in slot.

Comment: @BenjaminT OK, I fixed that.